# Can we join two lists in `setUnion` function in Terraform, instead of concatenating the two lists first and then applying `toset` function

Tags: terraform

I have two lists which need to be joined before being used in `for_each`. Can the `setunion` be used directly with lists or each list needs to be casted using `toset` before `setunion` can be used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `setunion` function knows that its arguments are supposed to be sets and so it will automatically convert from list to set if you pass in a list value.

In practice the following two expressions are equivalent:

```
toset(concat(list_a, list_b))
```

```
setunion(list_a, list_b)
```

The difference is only in the method Terraform takes to calculate the result. In the first case it will first construct a new list which is the concatenation of `list_a` and `list_b`, and then convert that result to a set. In the second case it'll convert `list_a` and `list_b` to sets *first* and then calculate the union of those two sets. Because of the definition of `setunion`, these two methods will always produce the same result.

---

I think you may be asking this question because for `for_each` Terraform does *not* automatically convert from a list to a set.

The `for_each` argument has a special rule to disable Terraform's normal automatic conversion rule in this case because during the early alpha/beta testing period for `for_each` the team observed that people were often confused about what assigning a list to `for_each` would mean:

Some people expecting it to behave like `count = length(list)`, while other people expected it to behave like `for_each = toset(list)`.

Because the difference between these is subtle and may cause problems with later updates if the wrong interpretation were used, the Terraform team chose to force module authors to be explicit about which of these two interpretations they mean, either by explicitly converting the list to a set or by using the `count` argument instead to indicate that they want to use numeric indices for instance keys.

However, Terraform doesn't actually care how you produce the set of strings assigned to `for_each`, so you can use *any* expression whose result is of that type. `setunion` when given sets of strings (or anything that can convert to sets of strings) will always produce a set of string as a result, and so a call to that function is also a valid thing to assign to `for_each`:

```
  for_each = setunion(a, b)
```

No explicit conversion is needed in this case because `setunion` inherently returns a list as part of its definition.